# Using named injection in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm using Guice for dependency injection and I'm a bit confused. There are two `Named` annotations in different packages:

`com.google.inject.name.Named` and `javax.inject.Named` (JSR 330?).

I'm eager to depend on `javax.inject.*`. Code sample:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

public class MyClass
{
    @Inject
    @Named("APrefix_CustomerTypeProvider")
    private CustomerTypeProvider customerTypeProvider;
}
```

In my naming module I may have the following line:

```
bind(CustomerTypeProvider.class).annotatedWith(...).toProvider(CustomerTypeProviderProvider.class);
```

The question: I'm curious what should I put where the dots are? I would expect something like `com.google.inject.name.Names.named("APrefix_CustomerTypeProvider")` but this one returns `com.google.inject.name.Named` while I need the one in `javax.inject`.

`CustomerTypeProviderProvider.class.getAnnotation(javax.inject.Named.class)` also does not fit well because the `CustomerTypeProviderProvider` (ignore  the stupid name, legacy issue) is not annotated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned on the Guice wiki, [both work the same](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JSR330). You shouldn't worry about that. It is even recommended to use `javax.inject.*` when available, just as you prefer too (bottom of the same page).

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.name.Names;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Main {
  static class Holder {
    @Inject @javax.inject.Named("foo")
    String javaNamed;
    @Inject @com.google.inject.name.Named("foo")
    String guiceNamed;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Holder holder = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule(){
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
        // Only one injection, using c.g.i.Names.named("").
        bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("foo")).toInstance("foo");
      }

    }).getInstance(Holder.class);
    System.out.printf("javax.inject: %s%n", holder.javaNamed);
    System.out.printf("guice: %s%n", holder.guiceNamed);
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
java.inject: foo
guice: foo
```